# Counting different weights in representations of Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

There is a well known way to compute dimensions of irreducible representations of classical Lie algebras using weights. However, there are weights that appear a few times in the representation. My question is: how can one know how many different weights appear in the representation? For example, a (1,1) representation of A2 is 8 -dimensional, but there are 2 coincident weights, and therefore we are left with just 7 different weights. So I am looking for a way to arrive to 7 and not to 8 in analogous cases, and specifically in the case of representations (1,1....1) of An.

Answer (score 6):

If you are specifically interested in the representation $(1,1,\dots,1)$ for $A_n$ (often denoted by $\rho$ in the literature), then this has a very nice answer. The number of distinct weights is equal to the number of integral points of the "permutohedron," which is also equal to the number of forests of trees on $n$-labelled vertices. This is sequence A001858 of the OEIS.

More generally, the number of distinct weights in a given irreducible representation of any semisimple Lie algebra with highest weight $\lambda$ is the number of integral points in the weight polytope $\{W.\lambda\}$, where $W$ is the Weyl group.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for